# tensorflow: run model evaluation over multiple checkpoints

Tags: python, tensorflow

In my current project I train a model and save checkpoints every 100 iteration steps. The checkpoint files are all saved to the same directory (model.ckpt-100, model.ckpt-200 , model.ckpt-300 etc). And after that I would like to evalute the model based on validation data for all the saved checkpoints, not just the latest one.

Currently my piece of code for restoring the checkpoint file looks like this:

```
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)
ckpt_list = saver.last_checkpoints
print(ckpt_list)
if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
    print("Reading model parameters from %s" % ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    # extract global_step from it.
    global_step = ckpt.model_checkpoint_path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1]
    print('Succesfully loaded model from %s at step=%s.' %
            (ckpt.model_checkpoint_path, global_step))
else:
    print('No checkpoint file found')
    return
```

However, this restores only the latest saved checkpoint file. So how do I write a loop over all saved checkpoint files? I tried to get a list of the checkpoint files with saver.last_checkpoints, however, the returned list is empty.

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you save the model exactly? Are you building up the name for the output file yourself or do you use the `global_step` parameter when calling `saver.save(..)`?

Answer (score 3):

### Fastest solution:

`tensor2tensor` has a module `utils` with a script [`avg_checkpoints.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensor2tensor/blob/master/tensor2tensor/utils/avg_checkpoints.py) that saves the averaged weights in a new checkpoint. Let us say you have a list of checkpoints that you want to average. You have 2 options for usage:

1. From command line

   ```
   TRAIN_DIR=path_to_your_model_folder
   FNC_PATH=path_to_tensor2tensor+'/utils/avg.checkpoints.py'
   CKPTS=model.ckpt-10000,model.ckpt-20000,model.ckpt-100000

   python3 $FNC_PATH --prefix=$TRAIN_DIR --checkpoints=$CKPTS \ 
       --output_path="${TRAIN_DIR}averaged.ckpt"
   ```
2. From your own code (use `os.system`):

   ```
   import os
   os.system(
       "python3 "+FNC_DIR+" --prefix="+TRAIN_DIR+" --checkpoints="+CKPTS+
       " --output_path="+TRAIN_DIR+"averaged.ckpt"
   )
   ```

As an alternative to specifying a list of checkpoints and using the `--checkpoints` argument, you can just use `--num_checkpoints=10` to average the last 10 checkpoints.

### If you do not want a dependency on `tensor2tensor`:

Here is a code snippet that does not rely on `tensor2tensor`, but can still average a **variable number of checkpoints** (as opposed to ted's answer). Assume `steps` is a list of checkpoints that should be merged (e.g. `[10000, 20000, 30000, 40000]`).

Then:

```
# Restore all sessions and save the weight matrices
values = []
for step in steps:
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    path = model_path+'/model.ckpt-'+str(step)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(path+'.meta')
        saver.restore(sess, path)
        values.append(sess.run(tf.all_variables()))

# Average weights
variables = tf.all_variables()
all_assign = []
for ind, var in enumerate(variables):
    weights = np.concatenate(
        [np.expand_dims(w[ind],axis=0)  for w in values],
        axis=0
    )
    all_assign.append(tf.assign(var, np.mean(weights, axis=0))
```

Then you can proceed, however you prefer, e.g. saving the averaged checkpoint:

```
# Now save the new values into a separate checkpoint
with tf.Session() as sess_test:
    sess_test.run(all_assign)
    saver = tf.train.Saver() 
    saver.save(sess_test, model_path+'/average_'+str(num_checkpoints))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the files in the directory :

```
import os

dir_path = './' #change that to wherever your files are
ckpt_files = [f for f in os.listdir(dir_path) if os.path.isfile(
    os.path.join(dir_path, f)) and 'ckpt' in f]

for ckpt_file in ckpt_files:
    saver.restore(sess, dir_path + ckpt_file)
    global_step = ckpt.model_checkpoint_path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1]
    print('Succesfully loaded model from %s at step=%s.' %
          (ckpt.model_checkpoint_path, global_step))

    # Do your thing
```

add more conditions in the above list comprehension to be more selective like : `and 'meta' not in f` and so on depending on what's in that dir and the saver version you have

Answer (score 2):

Best solution, follow this [link](https://github.com/vonclites/checkmate)

I've been using this for a long while, it as neat.
You can save model according to whatever the metric you like.
It deletes the older checkpoints and loads the best checkpoints when restoring model.

If you are using accuracy as a metric set maximize= True to save model according to maximum accuracy.
If you are evaluating model on the basis of validation loss, you can set maximize flag to False to so that the model with least validation loss is saved.